# How to reverse the float order of heading & body with CSS?

Tags: css, layout, css-float

Without changing the HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>This is the Heading Which May be Long and Span Lines</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="thumb">
        <img></img>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>continues</p>
      <p>and wraps around the thumb</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>​
```

I need to style this so that the `img.thumb` floats left, and the `header h1` hangs to its right, and may wrap lines. The `h1` should be left-justified:

```
+------------+   Heading Text which May Be Long and
|            |   Thus would Span Lines
|   thumb    |
|            |   Content
+------------+   continues
and wraps around the thumb.
```

The layout (i.e. width of the heading and content) should fluidly adapt for width of the container. (The thumb is fixed width.)

Any way to achieve this with CSS3 without changing the order of the elements?  I can do this by fixing the width of the right column, but is there a way to specify "use the remaining space to the right of the float as the width"? (Without javascript, less, etc.)

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/agRx3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the thumb has a fixed width, you can use `position: absolute` to fix the location of the image. The header and content can then have `margin-left` which is slightly more than the thumb width

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SJvav/

Edit: To have the content wrap around the margin, let for the image and the text `float:left` and give the image a negative margin so its right beside the `h1` http://jsfiddle.net/SJvav/2/

Comment: good thinking but we need the content text to continue to wrap around the thumb.  updated: http://jsfiddle.net/SJvav/1/

Comment: actually, you know that is good enough because it's only the header that is mis-ordered here... I can float the rest of the content left and it will wrap. So I'll accept your answer. If you have a trick that would address this generally though I'd like to know the solution or see the fiddle.